# Node couldn't save data in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I'm on node 9.4.0. I tried to follow a tutorial on youtube - Traversy media (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrxDk1zLKdc). I did everything in the tutorial to parse data form html form made by pug and save the form data in a mongoDB table. Here is what I did.

```
//initailize
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodekb');
let db = mongoose.connection;

*********************************************
//check connection
db.once('open', function(){
    console.log('Connected to Mongodb');
});

//check for db error
db.on('error',function(err){
    console.log(err);
});

//init app
const app = express();

// bring in models
let Article=require('./models/article');


//load view engine
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view engine','pug');
//app.set('view engine','php');
//
//Body parser
app.set(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
//parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//home route
app.get('/',function(req,res){

Article.find({},function(err,articles){
    if(err){
        console.log('error');
    }
    else
    {
        res.render('index.pug',{
            title:'articles',
            allarticles: articles
        });
    }
})


    //res.send('Hello world');
});

//a route to another resource
app.get('/articles/add',function(req,res){
    res.render('add_article.pug',{
        title:'Add articles'
    });
});

// Add submit POST route
app.post('/articles/add',function(req,res){
    let article = new Article();
    article.title = req.body.title;//we need to install and include body-parser to parse form html body
    article.author = req.body.author;
    article.body = req.body.body;

    article.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });

    //console.log('Submitted');
    //return;
});


app.listen('3000',function(){
    console.log('server started on port 3000');
});
```

```
extends layout

doctype html
html
    head
        title node app with express framework
    body
            h2 #{title}

            form(method='POST', action='/articles/add')
                #form-group
                    label Title:
                    input.form-control(name='title', type='text')
                #form-group
                    label Author:
                    input.form-control(name='author', type='text')
                #form-group
                    label Body:
                    textarea.form-control(name='body')
                input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', value='submit')
```

Every time i fill data and submit, the db increments by one but blank record. for some reason the data is not reaching to the db but it actually increments one blank record.

Comment: it could be the client side code that is wrong - but ... have you tried any debugging on the code you posted e.g. `console.log(article.title)` etc to see what the server is "receiving"

Comment: I just checked the log i.e console.log(article.title) returns Undifined. which means there is problem on either the pug file or the article.title=req.body.title; statement.

Comment: indeed, check the browser developer tools console/network to see what the browser is sending